# PDF title removal

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

After creating a PDF from a MS word document using CC PDF convertor (my current choice of PDF creation) I uploaded it and noticed the title of the webpage was in the form:

**Microsoft Word myDocument.doc - myPDFDocument.pdf**

Presumably this is a "title" or metatag (if it is that?) that gets added in the conversion process.Is there anyway to stop, remove or edit this easily?